# filter over query results

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I am using `boss_db` with `erlang` and `chicagoboss`. AFAIK, we should always try to use minimum number of database queries. 
Right now, I'm making two separate queries for a single result.Which I assume can be done in one query but don't know how.

**Query1**

```
ActiveUserList = boss_db:find(user,
                             [{status, 'equals', active},{cid, 'equals', Cid}]).
```

**Query2**

```
ActiveLegalUserList = boss_db:find(user, 
     [{status, 'equals', active},{cid, 'equals', Cid},{legal, 'equals', true}]).
```

Is there any way to achieve this in one query? 
like:

```
ActiveLegalUserList = ActiveUserList:filter({legal, 'equals', true}).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `lists:filter()`

```
 ActiveLegalUserList = lists:filter(fun(User) -> 
                           User:legal() == true end, 
                       ActiveUserList).
```